# Get Rank attribute using Rally API

Tags: node.js, rally

Is it possible to get Rank attribute when fetching goals, initiatives, features, and user stories? I would like to order every of these levels by its own order property.
E.g. if I'm displaying Goals, I want to order them by Rank property, or if I'm displaying user stories I would like to order those by their own Rank (not by Rank of Goals that they belong to).

Is that possible, and how should I do that?
Here's my snippet of fetching features:

```
 async.map(goals, function(goal, cb) {
  self.restApi.query({
    type: 'portfolioitem/initiative',
    limit: Infinity,
    order: 'Rank',
    ref: goal.Children,
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'Children', 'Parent', 'Rank']
  }, cb);
 }, function (err, results) {
   // do something       
 });
```

How I should access that Rank property later? Looks like it is contained in DragAndDropRank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Rank field. Instead use DragAndDropRank, which is alphanumeric string, for example:

P!!$NO~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

You may sort by it:

```
order: 'DragAndDropRank'
```

and there is no need to fetch it if all you need is to sort by it.
The format of it does not lend itself to a meaningful display.

Comment: yes, that's it, thanks a lot! Tell me one more thing, where I can get further details regarding all the data that I can fetch (relationships between them, etc)?

Comment: @Ned, you're welcome. Web Services API documentation: https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/ ,esp. the ObjectModel https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp